# connecting to the data base by wamp

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

my problem is that i need to connect with the database by wamp localhost server .. i am making the connecting file connecting.php

```
  <?php 
      $servername = "localhost"; $username = "new1"; $password = "123";    // Create connection 
          $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);  //Check connection 
    if (!$conn) {     
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); } 

    echo "Connected successfully"; 
      ?>
```

on the desktop but it dosent seem any thing when i open this file with the browser

Comment: Do you get any errors? is your error reporting on?

Comment: Is this file in the wamp folder under the www sub folder? If not, place the file in there and then open it in the browser.

Comment: yes the folder of the project is in www folder @blackmambo

Comment: whats about this one  .. Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\loginsession\config.php on line 3 @EhsanT

Comment: Apparently you have some code in your `config.php` file which is using the deprecated `mysql_*` library. you have to change it to `mysqli_*`

Comment: yes that's it .. the problem was that i used mysql instead of mysqli ...

Comment: @blackmambo  thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start your wamp server as that will start the database server. Place you code in a .php file in the location in the picture below.

[[image: Place database code in the file and location depicted below.[1]]

Comment: Are you aware that the OP may have installed his wamp in another drive or path?!

Comment: Yeah. But I was just assuming he has the path listed. Can you show us your path @hikmat.sheqully